# Fade in after every line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Instead of individually doing a javascript for each line (separately creating a div that functions on a timer), I was wondering if it would be possible to fade in each line in the html that splits the line by "BR" by creating a universal javascript function.

1. Accepts a string, a div, and a speed as an argument.
2. Splits the line by "br>" and separated it into an array.
3. Fades in every line in the array in syncronization with the last line that previously faded in.

Comment: sure, you could do it creating an element (div/span) for every line inside your passed div, then fade-in with a delay (n*INTERVAL) for every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the comments in the code and let me know if something not clear..

**Tested on Chrome**

```js
function action(delay, str) {
  // split the string into array
  var lines = str.split('<br/>');

  $.each(lines, function(index, h) {
    // create a div to each line
    var div = $('<div />').html(h);
    // hide it, append it into the body
    div.hide().appendTo(document.body).delay(index * delay);
    // wait by the div index and the delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      // do the fadeIn
      div.fadeIn();
    }, index * delay);
  });
}

action(300, 'Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum <br/> Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum <br/> Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum <br/> Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum <br/>
  Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum <br/>
  Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum <br/>
  Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum
</div>

<hr />
```